What is the most accessible color to put over a blue background?
I lack knowledge in graphic design and in ophthalmology to conclude an answer:
Say I have some icon and/or text on top of a Blue background. What color should I dye that content that would be most accessible (most clear, most comfortable) to as much as readers as possible?
Edit: In this particular case, HTML-CSS blue background, the hex code of which is #0000FF.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are online tools and software which allow you to check WCAG accessibility - see a list here.  If I were you, I'd just make sure there's lots of contrast.  White would be your best bet probably.

No need to hunt opinions. Program WCAG color contrast analyzer shows it as numbers. The contrast ratio shows if a foreground-background color combination fulfills WCAG's criteria for accessibility. The needed contrast ratio depends on the usage - small text (14 pt or less) needs higher contrast ratio than larger text. In addition the wanted accessibility level affects. White on blue #0000FF gives the highest contrast. Yellow on the same blue gets close.

Try it. The analyzer is free.
The math formulas which define the color contrast are based on math models of vision. I must skip them. Sorry.

THe WCAG is okay but its not entirely perfect in its predictions.
